# Servlet Instance in the container

Tags: java, servlets

I knew only one servlet instance (One instance for one servlet basis) will be avilable in the web container. Is it possible to make a pool of instance in the web container ? Like a database connection? If i make a pool of servlet instance then how i can make that as a thread safe? (But i studied we can make only one servlet instance per servlet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand that it was an interview question. I would have answered it as follows:

> You can let the servlet implement [`SingleThreadModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) to get the container to create a pool of multiple instances of the same servlet class. The maximum pool size depends on the container used, on Tomcat for example, this is 20. But, a big **but**, this interface is deprecated since Servlet 2.4! We should actually be writing servlets in a thread-safe manner, without assigning request- and/or session scoped data as an instance variable of the servlet. This way it's safe to use a single servlet instance across multiple threads (read: across multiple HTTP requests).

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)

Answer (score 3):

Question is, why would you want to do that?

Servlet container instantiates single instance for each servlet declaration. That means, that you can have multiple servlet instances, but you need to declare the servlet as many times as many instances you want/need. This also brings the question of how servlets would be invoked ... they would need to be mapped to different paths.

Another way you can do this is to make a pool of handlers which your single servlet may call.

Re how to make them thread-safe: that depends on what exactly you want to do in those handlers. It's hard to tell you in general.

If you're asking about thread-safe pool, you can use Apache Commons Pool library, or some BlockingQueue (e.g. LinkedBlockingQueue) in Java: queue may contain your handlers. Servlet will `take()` first handler, use it, and `put()` it back after it's done. (This is just an example of course, there are many ways to implement pool).

But ... make sure you really need design like this, maybe your requirements can be satisfied by something simpler? (If your goal is to limit number of concurrent requests handled at the same time, maybe it's enough to just limit number of HTTP worker threads in your container? Or if that's not enough, you can use a limiting filter?)

Comment: This is the scenario i was faced in my interview!

Answer (score 0):

Defining a pool of servlets does not make sense as the Servlet itself is not a thread. The Web Container (e.g. Tomcat) maintains a thread pool which calls the Servlet instance. So if you want to increase the throughput (concurrent users) you have to increase your web containers' pool size.

Comment: You can have pool of any objects, not just threads. Sometimes it makes sense, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: @Peter Štibraný anyway, I cannot find reasons when I need a pool of instances of some servlet class.

Comment: @Alexandr, yup, it doesn't make sense for servlets.